# Nested Routes in React-Router-Dom Not Working

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have an App component which houses various routes.  One of those routes renders a Dashboard component, like so:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path = "/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path = "/about" component={AboutPage}/>
            <Route exact path = "/business" component={BusinessPage} />
            <Route exact path = "/business/dashboard/:business" component={DashBoard} />
            <Route exact path = "/business/laundromat/:businessName" component={DefaultPage} />
            <Route exact path = "/contact" component={Contact} />
            <Route exact path = "/login" component={LoginPage} />
            <Route exact path = "/sign-up" component={SignUpPage} />
            <Route exact path = "/:category/:zipCode" component={SearchPage} />
            <Route path="*" component={NotFound}/>  
          </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This component is stateful and passes data as props to various children components.  This works fine.  However, when I click on links to these components, the URL does not change.  I have decided to use "react-router-dom" and the useRouteMatch hook to create nested components.  I believe I have it setup correctly, but when I click on Links to these nested components I get my 404 page which is handled on my App component.

I am simply appending /business-info (etc) to the Path mentioned above within my Dashboard Component. I would like to avoid nesting these routes within my App, but every time I click on one of these links it hits the catch all 404 path.  Is it possible to append text after a :param? I only have access to the data I need to pass down within the Dashboard...   Here is what my route looks like within my Dashboard Component:

```
import { useRouteMatch, Link, Route, Switch  } from 'react-router-dom';
import BusinessInfo from "../components/DashboardBusinessInfo";
import AccountInfo from "../components/DashboardAccountInfo";
import Services from "../components/DashboardServices";
const {path, url} = useRouteMatch();
<Switch>
    <Route path={`${path}/business-info`} element={
        <BusinessInfo 
            name={stateObject.businessName} 
            phone={stateObject.phone} 
            address={stateObject.address} 
            category={stateObject.categoryName}
            hours={stateObject.hours}
            website={stateObject.website}
            zip={stateObject.zip}
            city={stateObject.city}
            street={stateObject.street}
            setLink = {selectLinks}
            update={updateCall}
        />}
    />
    <Route path={`${path}/account-info`} element={<AccountInfo businessName={stateObject.businessName} setLink = {selectLinks}/>}/>
    <Route path={`${path}/services`} element={
        <Services
            category={linkControl.servicesCategory}
            data={stateObject}
            update={updateCall}
        />}
    />
</Switch>
```

Version: react-router-dom@5.2.0

Comment: Could you include some more of your code as it is hard to help you debug your issues without seeing whats going on.

Comment: Please share a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), we can't help debug code we can't see. Please also confirm which version of `react-router-dom` you are using as it seems you are mixing both the version 5 and version 6 `Route` APIs & syntax. From your project directory run `npm list react-router-dom`.

Comment: Done.  Sorry for not including more code.

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the `exact` from your parent route when you are using nested routes.

```
<Route path="/business/dashboard/:business" component={DashBoard} />
```

Exact means 'When true, will only match if the path matches the location.pathname exactly' so all of your nested routes dont match it exactly so it wont go into them.

Check out the reactrouter v5 example for it and you can see that `/topics/` isn't using exact.
https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting

Comment: Thanks.  I will give that a shot!

Comment: I added exact on the parent route and scratching my head why the child routes were not working. you saved my day. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that all your root level routes are ***exactly*** matching the URL path. This necessarily precludes them from matching any nested/sub-routes rendered by any matched components. In other words, when the path is `"/business/dashboard/someBusinessName/business-info"` the `"/business/dashboard/:business"` path no longer exactly matches and the `Dashboard` component is unmounted.

To resolve you must remove the `exact` prop so the path is treated as a path-prefix and can then match nested/sub-routes. You should also keep in mind that within the `Switch` component that path order and specificity matter! Order the route paths from more specific paths to less specific paths so the more specific paths can be attempted to be matched before the less specific ones. If you order the paths correctly there should be a nearly zero use-case for using the `exact` prop on the routes.

App

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage}/>

    <Route path="/business/dashboard/:business" component={DashBoard} />
    <Route path="/business/laundromat/:businessName" component={DefaultPage} />
    <Route path="/business" component={BusinessPage} />

    <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
    <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
    <Route path="/sign-up" component={SignUpPage} />
    <Route path="/:category/:zipCode" component={SearchPage} />
    <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="*" component={NotFound}/>  
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Dashboard

Since you are using `react-router-dom` v5 the `Route` components don't take an `element` prop, this is new prop in v6 that replaced `component`, `render`, and `children` function props. You can just render the components as wrapped children since you are passing along additional props.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path={`${path}/business-info`}>
    <BusinessInfo 
        name={stateObject.businessName} 
        phone={stateObject.phone} 
        address={stateObject.address} 
        category={stateObject.categoryName}
        hours={stateObject.hours}
        website={stateObject.website}
        zip={stateObject.zip}
        city={stateObject.city}
        street={stateObject.street}
        setLink = {selectLinks}
        update={updateCall}
    />
  </Route>
  <Route path={`${path}/account-info`}>
    <AccountInfo
      businessName={stateObject.businessName}
      setLink={selectLinks}
    />
  </Route>
  <Route path={`${path}/services`}>
    <Services
      category={linkControl.servicesCategory}
      data={stateObject}
      update={updateCall}
    />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I will reformat my code and see if it works!